# Composite Primary Key - Dynamodb for Rust

Tags: rust, amazon-dynamodb

How does one define a composite key in dynamodb in rust? Currently we are creating our table similar to the rust CRUD github official example

```
    match client
        .create_table()
        .table_name(table_name)
        .key_schema(ks)
        .attribute_definitions(ad)
        .provisioned_throughput(pt)
        .send()
        .await
    {
        Ok(_) => println!("Added table {} with key {}", table, key),
        Err(e) => {
            println!("Got an error creating table:");
            println!("{}", e);
        }
    };
```

In python and JS you can pass in a dictionary object to .key_scheme and .attributes, but in the Rust implementation it seems that key_scheme is defined as

```
        pub fn key_schema(mut self, input: crate::model::KeySchemaElement) -> Self {
            self.inner = self.inner.key_schema(input);
            self
        }
```

So we're not sure how to create a composite primary key!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Going off the [documentation](https://docs.rs/aws-sdk-dynamodb/latest/aws_sdk_dynamodb/client/fluent_builders/struct.CreateTable.html#method.key_schema) it appears you would call `.key_schema` multiple times for a composite key. The docs say:

> Appends an item to `KeySchema`.
>
> To override the contents of this collection use `set_key_schema`.
>
> [...]
>
> For a composite primary key (partition key and sort key), you must provide exactly two elements, in this order: The first element must have a `KeyType` of `HASH`, and the second element must have a `KeyType` of `RANGE`.

So it appears your definition should look like:

```
client
    .create_table()
    .table_name(table_name)
    .key_schema(ks1)
    .key_schema(ks2)

// or

client
    .create_table()
    .table_name(table_name)
    .set_key_schema(Some(vec![ks1, ks2]))
```

And a similar pattern is documented for `attribute_definitions` and `set_attribute_definitions`. Disclaimer: I'm not very familiar with DynamoDB, I'm just relaying the documentation.